# How to verify latest kernel version?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel, xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu after Ubuntu, running in dualboot. So Xubuntu controls the grub. Every time I update kernel on Ubuntu - will Ubuntu load the latest version of a kernel? (I mean the grub is not updated, it may be updated by Xubuntu. And I don't want to write the grub to MBR from Ubuntu)

I can't find information which is latest kernel version for trusty, but mine is `3.13.0-24-generic`

Comment: Depends on your Xubuntu grub menu. Most times it is fixed to a kernel version it reads from Ubuntu's grub menu and you need to run sudo update-grub in Xubuntu to find the new entry in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

To check what kernel version you are running; `$ uname -r`

As your grub controlled by Xubuntu, you should update the grub by typing;

```
sudo update-grub
```

***make sure to run this command on Xubuntu as it is the one who control the grub***

Also note, when you do `$ sudo update-grub` it will automatically detect present kernel versions on both partitions and update the grub accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it at

online: https://www.kernel.org/

Or you can add linus torvalds to your google plus: +LinusTorvalds

directly from git: https://github.com/torvalds/linux

at google+ he occasionally cries, gets angry and falls on their updates

Answer (score 0):

`uname -a`

check your kernel version form the above command and go to [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/) see what the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my trouble.
Here you can check latest version of kernel for Ubuntu
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux

I checked it, and installed the package `linux-generic-lts-trusty`. Then rebooted, then entered `uname -r` in terminal - the version was the same. The problem wasn't solved. So I installed `grub-customizer` and wrote GRUB to MBR. After another reboot I have the latest kernel.

Comment: You said in your question that you don't want to control the grub from Ubuntu. So, this is not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

1.

first of all know your current version by typing following command in terminal

```
uname -r
```

then check on [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)  link to know that your running system is the latest one available in market

2.
You can also if you are not running a LTS version you will be prompted that a new version is available.

If both methods do not satisfy you read this 
[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)